# Nested dictionaries - obtaining values (Python)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have a JSON file, converted from XML which was originally equation: x^2 + 4*x + 4 = 0:

```
{
  "mrow": {
    "mrow": {
      "msup": {
        "mi": "x",
        "mn": "2"
      },
      "mo": [
        "+",
        "+"
      ],
      "mrow": {
        "mn": "4",
        "mo": "*",
        "mi": "x"
      },
      "mn": "4"
    },
    "mo": "=",
    "mn": "0"
  }
}
```

When I open this file with Python I get nested dictionaries, like this:

```
{'mrow': {'mrow': {'msup': {'mi': 'x', 'mn': '2'}, 'mo': ['+', '+'], 'mrow': {'mn': '4', 'mo': '*', 'mi': 'x'}, 'mn': '4'}, 'mo': '=', 'mn': '0'}}
```

Is there a simple way to obtain only the values representing the initial equation, so that I get the initial equation again?

Comment: There is `json.dump()`

Comment: You mentioned this comes from an XML. It makes me think that is actually [MathML](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-math-970515/section2.html) format. I'd check if there's any Python package that parses it ([mathdom](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mathdom)) maybe?

Comment: You can **not** safely get the initial equation with this representation, because keys order is not preserved in a Python object. You could get `x^2 + 4*x + 4 = 0` or `x^2 + 4*x + 4 0 =`, or anything else.

Comment: maybe try parsing the original XML data to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def parse_obj(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        items = []
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == 'mrow':
                items.append(parse_obj(value))
            elif key == 'msup':
                mi = parse_obj(value['mi'])
                mo = parse_obj(value['mn'])
                items.append("{mi}^{mo}".format(mi=mi, mo=mo))
            elif key in ['mi', 'mo', 'mn']:
                items.append(parse_obj(value))
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError((key, value))
        return " ".join(items)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return " ".join(parse_obj(value) for value in obj)
    else:
        return obj  # a string
```

With the following json content:

```
text = """\
{
  "mrow": {
    "mrow": {
      "msup": {
        "mi": "x",
        "mn": "2"
      },
      "mo": [
        "+",
        "+"
      ],
      "mrow": {
        "mn": "4",
        "mo": "*",
        "mi": "x"
      },
      "mn": "4"
    },
    "mo": "=",
    "mn": "0"
  }
}"""

json_decoder = json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
obj1 = json_decoder.decode(text)
print(parse_obj(obj1))
```

You get:

```
x^2 + + 4 * x 4 = 0
```

I think that there is a problem with `"mo": ["+", "+"]`…